# python post data with requests in python

Tags: python, authentication, http-post, python-requests

If I try to login to my account and it is not successful then I would have phrase `try again` in url source page. So I tried to write python script to login to my account and do stuff:

## Update

```
token=...#by xpath
session=requests.Session('http://example.com')
response=session.get('http://example.com')
cook=session.cookies
postdata={'token':token, 'arg1':'', 'arg2':'', 'name[user]': user, 'name[password]':password, 'arg3': 'Sign in'}
postresp=requests.post(url='http://example.com/sth', cookies=cook, data=post_data)
print postresp.content
```

Is there something wrong with postdata or etc?

I also sat cookies.

Comment: Perhaps some cookie is necessary.

Comment: @laike9m Ok...You mean I am not wrong, are I?

Comment: There's no right or wrong, just work or not work, you have to keep trying before it gets to work.

Comment: @MortezaLSC Can I have the url please? Please tag my name in your comment  while replying. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Md. Mohsin I really like Indian friends... pardon me..I am not erally keen on showing url....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to show the url - and its difficult to hit the bulls eye without it:-)

Here's my try let me know if it works or please comment with the error you get here after.

`Please note the following points:
-try to use a user agent in the headers
-Token needs to be fetched after calling the url (In the following case its the 5th line)`

```
session=requests.Session()
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"}
session.headers.update(headers)
response=session.get('http://example.com').content #I added this line
tree=html.fromstring(cont)                         #and this line 
token=tree.xpath('//*[@class="blah blah blah"]')
#cook=session.cookies -- You don't need this if you are continuing with the same session
postdata={'token':token, 'arg1':'', 'arg2':'', 'name[user]': user, 'name[password]':password, 'arg3': 'Sign in'}
postresp=session.post(url='http://example.com/sth', data=post_data) # use session.post instead of making a completely new request
print postresp.content
```

Also, please check if there is specific `content-type` if yes, then please add it to the headers

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: @MortezaLSC `session.get` is to use the same session throughout - the website might be using specific tokens for every session. So `session.get` and `session.post` uses the same session throughout. Not needing us to carry forward the cookies. And even avoids the token from being changed. On the other hand `requests.get` opens a new one time session altogther - so all cookies and token change here

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to do this, the first step is open Chrome(or FF if you like) and send a request

Press **F12**
[image]

Click that specific request, here I just refresh this page, for you, it's the login request
[image]

And you could see what's needed, there are always cookies, and just use these cookies when you imitate the request. Sometimes only copy and pasting cookies won't work, if so, you have to make clear the meaning of every field of those cookies, and make one yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you... I had done it before... and there where parameters I had to post... But I don't know why there is no establishrd connection

Comment: pardon for delay... I have checked it and I sat coockies. So please see update...

Comment: @MortezaLSC I think it's OK, using requests' `Session` is very convenient. Is it working?

Comment: @MortezaLSC Why not show us `postresp`? What's the return code?

Comment: I do: print postresp ,,, The asnwer is: <Response [200]>

Comment: @MortezaLSC And what's the content of `postresp`?

Comment: pardon me... I am not really keen on showing it... but when I print `postresp.url` it returns me a faild login url... but my user pass is correct actually

Comment: @MortezaLSC http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0-0/user/quickstart/#response-content